# Animate not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

This is my jQuery function:

```
var flashField = function ($field) {
    var colour = $field.css('background-color'); // gets colour ok
    $field.css( 'backgroundColor', '#FF0000' ); // sets background ok
    $field.animate({ 'backgroundColor': colour }, 1500); // nada
}
```

I want to grab the element's current background, switch it to red and then fade back to the original colour.

However the `animate` function doesn't do anything and no errors are shown in the console.

What have I done wrong? Have tried searching but can't find anything that shows bad syntax or whatever.

(testing in Chrome 45.0.2454.93 m)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I didn't expect this from you! `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar LOL. I was too lazy, didn't want to read it. `:P`

Comment: I know what you mean - 4 lines of code - who has time for that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `jquery-ui.js` to animate colours. From the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/animate/):

> jQuery UI bundles the jQuery Color plugins which provides color animations as well as many utility functions for working with colors.

```js
  $(function() {
    var state = true;
    $("#button").click(function() {
      if (state) {
        $("#effect").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
          color: "#fff",
          width: 500
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        $("#effect").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          color: "#000",
          width: 240
        }, 1000);
      }
      state = !state;
    });
  });
```

```css
.toggler {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#effect {
  width: 240px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
#effect h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Animate</h3>
    <p>
      Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Toggle Effect</button>
```

Comment: Thanks - reading now...

Comment: @bukko I have updated my answer with the sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but all I needed was the clue about jQuery UI. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow impatient! okay okay...

Comment: @bukko Ha ha... Sorry... `:D`